# How to get the JSON keys or keyField?

Tags: javascript

I have JSON:

```json
{
  "category":[
    {"id":"1","name":"Decorative Objects", "bg_url":"decorative.jpg","url":"/decorative"},    
    {"id":"2","name":"Asian Arts", "bg_url":"asian_art.jpg","url":"/asian_arts"}, 
    {"id":"3","name":"Glassware", "bg_url":"glassware.jpg","url":"/glassware"}, 
    {"id":"4","name":"Antiques", "bg_url":"antique.jpg","url":"/antiques"}
  ]
}
```

I manage to get the first key by using

```
keyIndex = Object.keys(data)[0];
```

But after that, I would like to get also the inside keyField.

I tried

```
keyField = Object.keys(data)[keyIndex][0];
```

but no luck. I'm newbie in JavaScript.

I would like to return:

```
{id,name,bg_url,url}
```

I don't need to return the other. Only the first [0].

**I've found the solution:**

```
keyIndex = Object.keys(data)[0];
keyField = Object.keys(data[keyIndex][0]);
```

Comment: Try `data.category[0]` if you want the object with "Decorative Objects" as its name.

Comment: `keyIndex` is a string, but `Object.keys` returns an array with numeric indices.

Comment: @james it work. keyField = Object.keys(data.category[0]); return the keys. But it defeats the purpose because "category" could change to something else like "items" or "tags", that is why i would like to use variable to access the object.

Comment: thanks for the help. i should have read more.

Comment: `keyIndex` is less an "index" in the traditional sense of the word. It's merely the first key returned by `Object.keys()`. BTW, the solution that you "found" does not return what you said you'd like to return. It returns `[ "id", "name", "bg_url", "url" ]`, not `{id,name,bg_url,url}`

Comment: @HereticMonkey it doesnt return {id,name,bg_url,url}, but when i try to split(','), it doesnt split. until i found that there is function ".join()", took me 20 minutes to figure it out. 

            keyIndex = Object.keys(data)[0];
            keyField = Object.keys(data[keyIndex][0]);
            keyString = keyField.join(',');
            keySplit = keyString.split(",");

now keySplit returns the array i wanted. but is there any optimal way to do this(not having 4 variables)?

Comment: `keyField` already contains the data you want. Why are you joining and splitting them apart again?!?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays, or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `keyIndex` as an index on `object`, not the result of `Object.keys()`. Since this is an array of objects, you then have to index that to get the first object. Finally, call `Object.keys()` on that to get the nested keys.

```js
const data = {
  "category":[
    {"id":"1","name":"Decorative Objects", "bg_url":"decorative.jpg","url":"/decorative"},    
    {"id":"2","name":"Asian Arts", "bg_url":"asian_art.jpg","url":"/asian_arts"}, 
    {"id":"3","name":"Glassware", "bg_url":"glassware.jpg","url":"/glassware"}, 
    {"id":"4","name":"Antiques", "bg_url":"antique.jpg","url":"/antiques"}
  ]
}

const keyIndex = Object.keys(data)[0];
const nestedKeys = Object.keys(data[keyIndex][0]);

console.log(nestedKeys);
```